# How to measure 915 MHz LoRa RF power?

Tags: power, rf, lora

I'm having trouble measuring the RF power output of a nominally 20 dBm max (100 mW) LoRa board.

First I tried feeding the output into a cheap handheld spectrum analyzer through various attenuators. The analyzer had a background reading of -100 dB with no RF input. This level changed to -91 with a 20 dB attenuator, -93 with a 30 dB and -95 with a 50 dB between the LoRa board and the meter during transmit.

When I could not make sense of these results I fed the RF into a dummy load through an old moving coil Bird RF wattmeter, it showed 20 mW continuous.

Is measuring RF power for chirping modulations like raw LoRa more complicated than this? How can I validate that the RF power output of this board is in fact set to the correct 20 dBm level?